# splite string using mutilple characters

Tags: actionscript-3, string, date, time, flex4

what I need is simple thing, I have string which cantains data - time retrived from mySQL in mySQL format HH:MM:SS YY-MM-DD what I need is to split this string in actionscript to array of numbers like this
HH
MM
SS
YY
MM
DD

so I can compare it with current time, any one know how to splite using multiple delimiters at first, then compare it with current time. this is my work until now

```
            var param:Array = datetime.split(" :-");

            var currentTime:Date = new Date();
            var seconds:uint = currentTime.getSeconds();
            var minutes:uint = currentTime.getMinutes();
            var hours:uint = currentTime.getHours();
            var days:uint = currentTime.getDay();
            var monthes:uint = currentTime.getMonth();
            var years:uint = currentTime.getFullYear();

            if(int(param[3]) > years)
                return years + " سنة ";
            if(int(param[4]) > monthes)
                return monthes + " شهر ";
            if(int(param[5]) > days)
                return days + " يوم ";
            if(int(param[0]) > hours)
                return hours + " ساعة ";
            if(int(param[1]) > minutes)
                return minutes + " دقيقة ";
            if(int(param[2]) > seconds)
                return seconds + " ثانية ";

            return param[0] + " يوم ";
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>To solve your specific question, you might consider replacing the characters to be the same, and then split on that one. Use `datetime.replace(/[ :-]/g, "|")` and then split on "|". (I didn't check the correctness of the regexp).</strike> What Tyler says is more elegant: `datetime.split(/[ -:]/)`. I stand for the rest though:

What MySQL outputs (via php?) is a standard date notation. You could try and use the [Date.parse(dateString)](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Date.html#parse%28%29) to get a timestamp from it, and convert that into a date object by passing it as the sole constructor parameter:

```
recordedTime = new Date(Date.parse(datetime));
```

You could then compare the two date objects directly.

```
if (recordedTime.getFullYear() > currentTime.getFullYear()) { ... }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Split allows the delimiter to be a regexp, so you can say this or that. Something like this:

```
myStr.split(/:|-/)
```

Good luck!

Comment: I didn't know split() could take a regex, thanks @Tyler! But shouldn't the regex then be `/[ -:]/` to make sure it splits on just one character?

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple characters, with separated by pipe |

```
myStr.split(/:|-|[|\(|\)]/)
```

make sure to use \ if you use ( ) and similar, so ( )